# Why does a monotonic function always have a positive rate of change?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Based on my book

> The rate of change of $f(u)$ as $u$ changes can be measured by looking at the change in $f$ between two values of $u$, divided by the change in $u$:
>   $$\frac{Δf}{Δu} = \frac{f(u_2)-f(u_1)}{u_2-u_1}$$For a monotonic transformation, $f(u_2)-f(u_1)$ always has the same sign as $u_2-u_1$. Thus a monotonic function always has a positive rate of change. This means that the graph of a monotonic function will always have a positive slope, as depicted in Figure 4.1A.[image: monotonic and non monotonic graphs]

Now what I don't understand is if the monotonic function is as simple as $f(u) = u +1$ *(Changing it slightly from the non-monotonic function)* how come it comes it will always have a positive rate of change compared to the non-monotonic function?

Comment: 1.  What does "normal function" mean in this context. 2. Do you know about the Cantor function?

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you very much for your quick reply, by normal function I mean the non monotonic one (so in my case $f(u) = u$)

Comment: I still really don't know what you are asking.  That everything is called $f$ is no help.

Comment: Unless I'm blatantly missing something, this is an odd definition of *monotonic.* Usually a function that only decreases would be considered monotonic too. But there might be debate about whether it's allowed to have sections where it stays constant.

Comment: @timtfj so $f(u) = u-1$ ?

Comment: I wouldn't trust that book very much if I were you, since that excerpt is quite misleading. The slope isn't $\Delta f/\Delta u$, it's the limit of that thing as $\Delta u \to 0$. And even if $f$ is strictly increasing, there may be points where the slope is zero, like for $f(u)=u^3$ at $u=0$.

Comment: I'm still trying to work out what the heck they're saying. It's simply *not true* that a monotonic function must have a positive slope. That would be a *monotonically increasing* function. So either they're saying something else, or they're wrong.

Comment: For instance $f(x)=1-x$ iwould be monotonically decreasing since it has negative slope everywhere.

Comment: Part of the puzzle here maybe that the excerpt is referring to a "monotonic transformation". Is that defined in an earlier page?